# Sonata over REST services

Tags: sonata-admin, sonata

Is there any project for integrate CRUD REST services into the SonataAdminBundle? like ORMAdminBundle, MongoDBAdminBundle or PhpcrAdminBundle, but implementing the CRUD operations from REST services. It has never been discussed? What would be the best way to address this?

Answer (score 0):

Official bundle for CRUD support is not exist. You can add feature issue on github. Will be noce when you add example where current system is not enought or implement work will be equal to new functionality.